# replacing missing values(NAs) with white space(" ") or dot(".") while exporting a dataframe using write.csv

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a typical data frame that contains missing values, I want to export this data into a cvs or an excell workbook but I want to handle the missing values differently because I will want to use this data frame in STATA which does not accept NA as missing value.

I know r by default handles any missing value as NA, is there to tell R to handle this differently while exporting? say use a white space or dot to mean a missing value in my exported file that I will use in STATA?

Thank you

Comment: When exporting your data frame into a csv file, specify the `na` argument in [write.csv](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.1/topics/write.table). For Excel file, specify `showNA` in [write.xlsx](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.5.7/topics/write.xlsx)

Comment: The solutions listed below should work if your data really contains nulls. Are you sure that they are not actually "NA" strings? E.g. `c("NA","NA")` != `c(NA,NA)`

Answer (score 3):

From `?write.csv`:

> na the string to use for missing values in the data.

E.g. `write.csv(x, file = "foo.csv", na='.')`

Comment: Hi Otto, thanks, but still not working for this data set!

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table("col1" = c(1,2,NA),
                 "col2" = c(NA,NA,0))

> dt
   col1 col2
1:    1   NA
2:    2   NA
3:   NA    0
```

Replace `NA`s with "."

```
dt[is.na(dt)] <- "."
> dt
   col1 col2
1:    1    .
2:    2    .
3:    .    0

write.csv(dt,"test2.csv",na=".",row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried that code, my result export file still has NAs in columns with missing values

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new dataset where you replace NA for a character.

E.g. `data[is.na(data)]<-"."`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on my comment:

```
df <- mtcars
df$miss <- NA
# NA values as empty cells 
write.csv(df, file = "df.csv", na = "") # for csv file
xlsx::write.xlsx(df, file = "df.xlsx", showNA = FALSE) # for excel file
```

Comment: I am so supprised, its working perfectly well for these test data set, guess I need to look at my data set well

Comment: Make sure you didn't change the default pattern for missing values (ie `NA`) in your data before the export.